# Customising Web-logics default 404 error page

Tags: redirect, weblogic

I am running weblogic 9. When I enter an incorrect URL below the application root I redirect 404 request to a customized error page.

Eg. `http://localhost:7001/myApp/non-existent` redirects to my customised error page.

Is there a way to do this for all incorrect URLs entered, not necessarily below the application root?

Eg. `http://localhost:7001/anything_non-existent` should redirect to my customized error page, not the web-logic default one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The application's web.xml is where you define the `error-page` for  `<error-code>404</error-code>`

`http://localhost:7001/anything_non-existent` is actually looking for a missing web application.

If you have a web server like Apache in front of Weblogic, that is the right place to trap this and redirect to 404.